# Program get stuck after thread cancellation

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

Here, I am creating 10 threads and cancelling this threads inside their function. But sometimes, frequently, program get stucks, not responding. When I look the system monitor, I see the waiting channel is **futex_wait_queue_me**. What is the reason ? Rarely, I get segmentation fault, can it be related ? I know that, there is a chance that pthread_cancel function can runs with invalid threads like already cancelled threads or uninitialized threads, but I cannot understand the deadlock or segmentation fault.

```
pthread_t th[10];

void cancel()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        pthread_cancel(th[i]);
}

void* thf(void * arg)
{   
    pthread_setcanceltype(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ASYNCHRONOUS,NULL);
    cancel();
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        pthread_create(&th[i],NULL,thf,NULL);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        pthread_join(th[i],NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `cancel()` function cancels all threads every time it is called, not just the active thread, which I'm guessing isn't what is desired. It also has the potential to call `pthread_cancel()` on uninitialized thread objects (e.g. if the first thread calls `cancel()` before the other threads are all created). This is where the deadlocks and segfaults are coming from.

If you want to only cancel the current thread, you can use `pthread_cancel(pthread_self())`.

Comment: So, I am expecting that pthread_cancel function returns an error about the given thread is already cancelled or given thread is not a valid (uninitialized yet ) thread. Is it about implementation of pthread_cancel method ? Actually my main goal is, in such a case, I want to be able to cancel all threads

Comment: @tango-1: No, if you pass an uninitialised value to `pthread_cancel()`, there is no guarantee you'll get an error return - anything could happen, like crashing or a deadlock.

Comment: @caf thanks. Is there a standart pattern to cancel all threads and exit without any leaks ?

Comment: @tango-1: The most reliable way to do it is to have all threads be responsible for stopping work and exiting themselves when they are notified.